# Thymeleaf ClassLoaderTemplateResolver can't find email templates, but only on linux

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

We are currently using Thymeleaf for a Spring MVC website. Recently, we decided to use it for processing rich HTML email templates. I followed the example here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/springmail.html.

The ClassLoaderTemplateResolver has a prefix of "email/" and the templates are stored in an "email" sub-folder under "src/main/resources/", which appears to be where it looks for them.

**Everything works fine on my development machine using Windows 7/Tomcat7/Eclipse, but fails when I publish the .war file to Amazon's EC2 (Linux environment/Tomcat7)** and attempt to generate an email. This is the error:

> ERROR C: U: org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine -
>   [THYMELEAF][pool-2-thread-2] Exception processing template
>   "email_template.html": Resource resolution by ServletContext
>   with org.thymeleaf.resourceresolver.ServletContextResourceResolver can
>   only be performed when context implements
>   org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext [current context:
>   org.thymeleaf.context.Context]

I can get this error message to happen on my windows dev machine if I delete/rename the template from /src/main/resources/email, So I'm assuming the ClassLoaderTemplateResolver can't find the template and then the template engine tries the ServletContextResourceResolver which can't be used because it doesn't have a WebContext.

The java-based configuration looks like the following:

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    final ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(appSettings.getDefaultEncoding());
    resolver.setOrder(2);
    resolver.setCacheable(!appSettings.isDebugMode() || !appSettings.isOneBoxMode());
    return resolver;
}

@Bean ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
    final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("email/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(appSettings.getDefaultEncoding());
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
     final Set<TemplateResolver> templateResolvers = new HashSet<TemplateResolver>();
     templateResolvers.add(templateResolver());
     templateResolvers.add(emailTemplateResolver());
     engine.setTemplateResolvers(templateResolvers);
    return engine;
}
```

And the code to generate the email looks like:

```
final String template = "email_template.html";

// prepare the context
final Context ctx = new Context(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());

// create the body using ThymeLeaf
final String htmlContent = templateEngine.process(template, ctx);
```

Strangely, I've seen examples of the ClassLoaderTemplateResolver with a prefix of "/META-INF/templates" and similar. Doesn't the path have to be under "src/main/resources" and NOT "/src/main/webapp"? I've also tried to replace it with a FileTemplateResolver, but no matter what I tried, I couldn't figure out where to put the template files and what path to set the prefix to.

What could be different between my windows dev machine and Amazon's linux box? At first, I assumed that case-sensitivity of filepaths might be the culprit, but I eliminated that as a possibility.
Help!

Answer (score 2):

*annnnnnnd I'm an idiot*... I had a back slash between a folder name where the email templates are stored and the email template name, e.g. "folder\template.html", instead of "folder/template.html". this worked on windows, but not on linux.

Comment: System.getProperty("file.separator")

Comment: The error message is a bit misleading.  I mistakenly moved an entire directory of thymeleaf templates to another directory and was receiving this error.  Glad you posted it and your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy the war locally? Or are you testing in eclipse? If you aren't using the war locally, package up the war just like you do when you deploy it. Unzip it and verify that your templates are in WEB-INF/classes

Just a side note about META-INF, I've hosted config files off of /META-INF/ for spring projects before, its my SpringMVC context config which I stored in WEB-INF.